# Finding the missing variable Trigonmetry

Tags: trigonometry

Use the formula $s=rwt$ to find the missing variable.

$s=2π/3\text{ km}$

$r=5\text{ km}$

$t= 3\text{ sec}$

When I try to solve the problem I just plug in the values. which is $2π /3=5(3)w$

which gets me $10π $ yet the answer is $2π /45$ radians per second

Comment: Your equation is setup correct and gives the correct answer. Double check your algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You divided incorrectly.

$$\frac{2\pi}{3} = 15 \omega \Rightarrow \frac{1}{15}\frac{2\pi}{3} = \omega = \frac{2\pi}{45}\omega$$